# Javascript code causing IE to freeze (.addClass and .removeClass)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Can you guys see why the following is causing IE to crash?  I had to basically comment everything out and eventually found this was causing the crash, more specifically, when .addClass and/or .removeClass is run inside the if conditions:

```js
if ( percentExpenses > 50 && percentExpenses < 80 ) {
    $('.progress-bar-expenses')
        .removeClass('progress-bar-success')
        .addClass('progress-bar-warning');
} else if ( percentExpenses >= 80 ) {
    $('.progress-bar-expenses')
        .removeClass('progress-bar-success progress-bar-warning')
        .addClass('progress-bar-danger');
} else {
    $('.progress-bar-expenses')
        .addClass('progress-bar-success');
}
```

I am merely adding the old bootstrap progressbar properties.  Could one of those properties be causing the issue?

```css
.progress-bar-danger {
    background-color: #dd514c;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ee5f5b, #c43c35);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ee5f5b), to(#c43c35));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ee5f5b, #c43c35);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ee5f5b, #c43c35);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ee5f5b, #c43c35);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffee5f5b', endColorstr='#ffc43c35', GradientType=0);
}
```

**Live Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Hs37H/1/

Using IE11 on Windows 7

Comment: What do you mean by "crash"? As in the whole browser closes? Which version(s) of IE?

Comment: @nnnnnn The entire browser freezes.  Nothing functions.  I can't even close with the X in top right.  I have to right click on icon in tray and close window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing here will necessarily cause Internet Explore to crash, however it is entirely possible that one of these classes could be adding transitions or animations that themselves cause Internet Explorer to crash. In the I have seen things like `transition: all 1s` crash Chrome, and Internet Explorer.

Aside from that possibility, there is nothing here that will crash a browser necessarily.

#### Update following review of demo

It appears the following lines are causing the freeze in Internet Explorer 9, 10, and 11 (8 is not affected):

```js
$('.progress').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    percentage();
});

$('.table').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    loadChart();
});
```

The problem here is that the first function adds classes to elements, triggering `DOMSubtreeModified` event, which calls `percentage()`, which adds classes, which triggers the `DOMSubtreeModified` event, which... you get the idea, right?

If you visited the [Mozilla Developer Network documentation for this event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/DOMSubtreeModified), you would read the following:

> Be very careful with this event it is easy to cause an infinite loop if you decide to change the DOM inside the event handler.

Your event handler does in fact change the DOM, by adding and/or removing classes. Your `loadChart()` method adds or removes a canvas element, which could trigger further `DOMSubtreeModified` events

#### Solution

The solution to this problem is to notify the application yourself when it's time to run `percentage` or `loadChart`. You can do this by using jQuery's `.trigger` method, and subscribing to custom events:

```js
$(".progress").on("percentage", percentage);
$(".table").on("loadChart", loadChart);
```

In the above example, when the custom "percentage" event is triggered on `.progress`, we will respond by calling the `percentage` function. Likewise for the `loadChart` event and function. All that is left now is to trigger these events on our own:

```js
function doSomethingMagical ( ajax ) {
    ajax.success(function () {
        // This results in the calling of function:percentage
        $(".progress").trigger("percentage");
    });
}
```

Comment: I am using Bootstrap's progress bar which uses transitions.  However, if I don't add or remove a class, then it's just a solid blue bar, and the transitions still work.

Comment: Does the progress bar transition `all` or specific properties? If it transitions all, modify it to explicitly state which properties you'd like to transition, and try again.

Comment: The transition is currently set to `transition: width .6s ease;`

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you comment that line out entirely?

Comment: See my update above.  Could a CSS property be causing the issue?

Comment: @Keven The only one that could be causing this, in my experience, is the `transition` property. Can you upload your example some place?

Comment: It already is, is there a private place where I can send you the url?

Comment: @Keven You can take your code and put it on http://jsfiddle.net. Just remove any sensitive information.

Comment: Alright, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/Hs37H/1/ I included enough to cause it to freeze.

Comment: Thank you; please post that in your question, and share the version of Internet Explorer you're using as well.

Comment: In response to your update, by triggering the event yourself, were you able to stop IE from crashing?

Comment: @Keven By removing those two function calls, I was able to stop IE from crashing. I am currently refactoring the code a little to see if it's the event you're subscribing to, or the code you're running as a result.

Comment: You led me to a solution.  My code is more repetitive, but uses less processing (I'm sure anyway... haven't tested it).  I just decided to remove the `DOMSubtreeModified` and decided to add `percentage()` and `loadChart()` to each success statement in my ajax calls.  That way they will only be called on page load, and on successful click of a button.  I appreciate the help!

Comment: HOWEVER, there is one slight bug I've noticed.  Every once-in-awhile the content isn't dynamically updated.  Tends to happen on a newly refreshed page, and it only happens sometimes.  It's difficult to reproduce.

Comment: @Keven The `percentage()` function is getting called in an infinite loop. I'm  investigating further right now. But that is killing Internet Explorer 9, 10, and 11 (http://jsfiddle.net/Hs37H/19/)

Comment: Hmmm... weird.  I'll look into it too.

Comment: Updated my answer to explain in more detail.

Comment: Yep, makes sense.  I'll avoid `DomSubtreeModified` from now on.  Besides working in IE, everything runs much faster now.  My progress bar and pie chart load much more quickly.   Thanks!

Comment: Check out [`MutationObservers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn254985(v=vs.85).aspx) instead ;) Just be careful not to cause DOM changes within the handler for a Observer that watches for DOM changes.